# Allow HTTP->HTTPS while blocking HTTPS->HTTP redirects in OkHTTP?

Tags: redirect, okhttp

With `OkHTTP` I have two methods for configuring redirects -

1. `followRedirects(boolean followRedirects)` -> Configures whether to allow redirection at all.
2. `followSslRedirects(boolean followProtocolRedirects)` -> Configures whether to allow `HTTP` -> `HTTPS` and `HTTPS` ->  `HTTP` redirects.

Though what I am looking to achieve is to allow `HTTP` -> `HTTPS` redirects while simultaneously blocking `HTTPS` -> `HTTP` redirection. The only way I can think of is to add an `OkHTTP` Interceptor as shown in the code below to check for request and response url protocols. Though I am not sure if it's the most optimum/correct way to achieve this as we are still making the calls to redirected url while doing `chain.proceed(request)`. Can anyone points me toward a better approach here. Thanks.

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                    if (!isValidRedirect(request.url(), response.request().url())) {
                        throw new IOException("Invalid redirect from secure server to insecure server");
                    }
                    return response;
                }
            })
            .build(); 



private static boolean isValidRedirect(HttpUrl url, HttpUrl newUrl) {
        //unless it's https, don't worry about it
        if (!url.url().getProtocol().equals("https")) {
            return true;
        }

        // If https, verify that we're on the same server.
        // Not being so means we got redirected from a secure link to a
        // different link, which isn't acceptable.
        return url.url().getHost().equals(newUrl.url().getHost());
    }
```

Comment: You should avoid `HttpUrl.url()`. Just get the protocol off the HttpUrl (via `scheme()`) and do the same the hostname (via `host()`). Way faster.

Comment: Thanks @JesseWilson. That makes sense.

Comment: @JesseWilson Do you think adding a network interceptor instead of an application one and detecting a 301 better serves my use case as that way I can abort an invalid redirected request before sending it.

Comment: I think you're better off turning off redirects in your OkHttpClient, plus an application interceptor to follow the redirects you like.

Comment: @JesseWilson Cool. That's definitely an option. Though I think it's easier to throw an Exception in a network Interceptor when you encounter an invalid redirect. That way the redirection part is still handled by OkHTTP and  I am also able to stop the invalid redirect. I am curious to know if you see any potential problems with this approach.